# Can I set a default context in an GraphQL request header?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, graphql

I am writing an app that makes a lot of API calls to the same GraphQL endpoint. Most us the same authorization header, but a few require a different access token.  In researching the problem, it looks like I can use header context to address this, but the issue is I only want to set up the endpoint once, so as soon as I load the schema it crashes because the context hasn't been set yet.

```
HTTP = GraphQL::Client::HTTP.new("https://example.com") do
    def headers(context)
      {"Authorization": context[:access_token]}
    end
  end
 # code breaks at below line because context hasn't been set
  SCHEMA = GraphQL::Client.load_schema(HTTP)
```

I want to be able to set some default value like 
`{"Authorization": context[:master_token]=ENV.fetch(MASTER_TOKEN)}`

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Turns out doing a simple conditional assignment does the trick.

`{"Authorization": context[:token] ||= ENV.fetch(MASTER_TOKEN)}`

So if `context[:token]` is `nil`, it will default to the `MASTER_TOKEN`